# Looking for web-based graph editing framework

Tags: javascript, flash, graph

Does anyone know of a web-based framework for interactively **editing** [graphs (nodes and edges)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics))? Flash or Javascript is fine. I'm looking for something like [GEF in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/), or [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/), or the [NetBeans graph framework](http://graph.netbeans.org/). Thanks!

**Just to be clear, I'm interested in editing tools for [mathematical graphs (nodes and edges)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)), not charting tools.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's [WireIt](https://github.com/neyric/wireit), which has a interface that is comparable to Yahoo pipes. There are a couple examples that look to be pretty graph-oriented.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is almost exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Excellent find.  I got to this post from Google because I was looking for an alternative to Signavio/Onyx, which are very similar to WireIt, but have a restrictive license.

Comment: The link no more works

Comment: @Romaan I updated the link. Although these days, something built on top of D3 (http://d3js.org/) will probably be a better solution

Comment: I agree @BenjaminWohlwend

Answer (score 4):

It's more of a technology demo than a framework, but you might want to check out this pure-JS implementation (using Processing.js) of a simple graph editor:

http://radokirov.com/graph-editor.js/

Comment: This is now at [http://radokirov.com/js-graph-editor/](http://radokirov.com/js-graph-editor/). I am the author, if anyone wants to contact me.

Comment: The link has changed again: http://radokirov.com/graph-editor.js

Answer (score 2):

I was a little disappointed I couldn't find anything like this either so I thought I would share my implementation using arbor.js

https://github.com/laxatives/Edit-Arbor.js

There's also a link to a demo on the UCBerkeley Engineering Ethics webpage in the repo README.

Answer (score -5):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is the best one I have used. It is works on JavaScript and it is FOSS.

I have also used [OpenFlashChart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) and [PHP/SWF Charts](http://www.maani.us/charts/index.php) (Flash based) but found the extra overhead of Flash a burden. Also PHP/SWF Charts requires registration if you want to get rid of the commercial links.

[JSCharts](http://www.jscharts.com/) also looks good, but I haven't tried it. And you do not get the source code.

Comment: As noted in the question, looking for node and edge graph editor, not charts.

Comment: Not looking for a charting framework.

Comment: Yes Richard, that was already pointed out in the first comment almost a year ago now.